# XRegExp failing on some strings

Tags: regex, typescript, xregexp

So I have an expression:

```
XRegExp.cache("^([\\w-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*)@((?:[\\w-]+\\.)*\\w[\\w-]{0,66})\\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\\.[a-z]{2})?)$", "i");
```

which I use to validate emails during registration, **emails can have custom domains so every one of them must pass**, e.g: foo@bar.baz(this does indeed pass).

My problem is that not every email passes validation(e.g: thisfails@proxima.solutions), so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: my case was failing because of {2,6}